# Fun web based programming environment for tablet?

Tags: mobile

Sometimes I am away from computer and have some spare time. I would love to do some programming just for fun or experiments. I can imagine something like a web site that can edit and execute JavaScript (or any other language is OK). But it must be ready for keayboardless tablet.

Unfortunately typing to google anything that contains JavaScript and IDE or Website, will give millions of links not suitable for this request. Hence I write here. This is not to start any flame or unproductive discussion. This is really the only option I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) allows you to write HTML/JavaScript/CSS in one editor and immediately run it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [TouchDevelop](https://www.touchdevelop.com/).  It's developed by Microsoft Research and allows you to create apps on your iPad, Android device, etc...